# SSIS packages behaving differently between environments

Tags: excel, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2012, ssis-2017

We have an SSIS package that imports data from Excel and updates a SQL table.
On the live environment we can run via Visual Studio 2010 (the version bundled with SQL 2012) before deploying to the SSIS catalogue to run automatically

Our development environment was recently upgraded from Visual Studio 2010 to 2017. The packages generally work fine when copied to the live server but we have noticed some examples where SSIS behaves differently between environments, I don't know if those differences existed before or not

For example we had an Excel file uploaded with some rows with null values (rather than just being blank) appended to the end of the actual data.
On live the OLEDB data source task fails with an OLE DB Source error

> value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data

This happened with both numeric and date columns.

However in the dev environment (exactly the same code and template) the template is read and the blank rows can be filtered out tidily

Does anyone know if there are any other environmental factors that could cause this other than the Visual Studio versions? It would make troubleshooting a lot easier if we could get the two environments to behave in the same way!

Comment: Are you still using SQL Server 2012 or you upgraded to SQL Server 2017? Are the installed Excel versions the same on both machines?

Comment: @Webbo the development environment has to match the production in terms of software otherwise this does not make sense not to expect issues.

Comment: @Arthur i agree with that, but he also must check - if they upgraded SQL to 2017 - that the packages `TargetServerVersion` property is set to `SQL Server 2017` since it will not change after upgrade and may cause some malfunctionality

Comment: @Hadi the TargetServerVersion is SQL 2012 which is correct for the live environment

Comment: @Arthur I'm aware of that, thanks, and it's something that needs to be resolved but it doesn't help me with my immediate issue

Comment: @Webbo is there a difference in office versions and service packs between both machines? Access Database Engine version?

Comment: @Webbo the proper path is to align the environments. Then upgrade the existing project. Then QA, deploy only when the QA results are of satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

To properly deploy packages, both the development and production environments need to be aligned. 
Then upgrade the existing project in development, QA, and deploy only when the QA results are of satisfactory.